# How Lebesgue integration solved the problem of a function being integrable but its limit is not integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My professor gave us the following form of Dirichlet function as an example of the problems we faced in Riemann integration:

$\{r_{n}\}$ enumeration $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$

$$ f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 &  \quad x \in \{r_{1}, ... , r_{n}\}  \\
      0 &   \quad \text{otherwise}. 
   \end{cases} $$

And he said that: each $f_{n}$ is integrable but its limit is not integrable.

**My questions are:**

1- why each $f_{n}$ is integrable but its limit is not integrable?

2- How did Lebesgue integration solve this problem?

Could anyone help me understand answers to these questions, please?

Comment: 1. follows from looking at the Darboux sums.

Comment: A typical approach to Lebesgue integral is to define the integral of a limit of sequence of functions as limit of integrals of these functions (this involves lot of technical details which I avoid here). So this is a feature by design.

Comment: In the current case we have $\int f_n=0$ and thus we define the Lebesgue integral $\int f=\lim\int f_n=0$.

Comment: 2. If you study Lebesgue measure & integration you will understand why, the TL;DR is that Lebesque integration (well, measure  really) allows the domain to be partitioned in a much more refined manner than Riemann integration. A finite number of non trivial intervals must contain point where $f$ is one and zero, whereas using a partition of the form $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $ [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ allows one to deduce that the integral is zero.

Comment: Are you speaking about DCT and BCT in your first comment? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: No, my comment is related to definition of Lebesgue integrals. A specific version is: let $f_n$ be an increasing sequence of step functions on interval $I$ such that $\lim \int_{I} f_n$ exists. Then $f_n$ converges almost everywhere in $I$ to some function $f$ and then we define $\int_{I} f=\lim\int_{I} f_n$. Difference of two functions like $f$ gives the class of Lebesgue integrable functions on $I$.

Comment: In your question, you should be able to observe that each $f_n$ is step function in $[0,1]$ and more importantly for each $x\in[0,1]$ the sequence $f_n(x) $ is increasing and hence the definition applies.

Comment: Step functions are too simple by nature and it is rather amazing that by taking limits of such functions we can generate a large class of functions which includes the class of Riemann integrable functions as a proper subset.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh when can I find this version of the definition of Lebesgue integrals .... for example in Royden 4th edition .... I am speaking about your comment that starts with the word "No"?

Comment: Also does the definition you mentioned in that comment should contain absolute values? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ...Also, what do you mean by "Difference of 2 functions like $f$ gives the class of Lebesgue integrable functions on $I$"?

Comment: My definition is taken from Apostol's _Mathematical Analysis_. Royden instead uses _simple functions_ (linear combination of characteristic functions of measurable sets). I find Apostol's book more suitable for self-study. A function $f$ is said to be Lebesgue integrable on $I$ if we can write $f=u-v$ where both $u, v$ are functions as described in my comments (ie they are limits almost everywhere of increasing sequence of step functions with the sequence of corresponding integrals being bounded).

Comment: @copper.hat what do you mean by "TL;DR"?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In your comment that starts with "In the current case" your third comment ..... I do not understand the integral sign at the first part of your comment here  $ \int f_{n} = 0$ is it the Lebegue integral sign or the Riemann integral sign ? because after that you defined the Lebesgue integration to be the limit of that integration. ..... Also, I do not understand why  $ \int f_{n} $ equals $0$? could you explain this, please?

Comment: @copper.hat  I do not understand how " Lebegues integration allows the domain to be partitioned in a much more refined manner than Riemann integration." ..... could you explain this more, please? ..... Also, I do not understand why you are saying" **A finite number** of non trivial intervals must contain point where f is one and zero, whereas using a partition of the form $Q∩[0,1]$ and $[0,1]∖Q$ allows one to deduce that the integral is zero."

Comment: @copper.hat Also, why you are saying that **a partition of the form $Q∩[0,1]$ and $[0,1]∖Q$ allows one to deduce that the integral is zero.**? could you please explain why the integration, in that case, is $0$?

Comment: @Smart20: The finite partition is the basis of Riemann integration, and so if $f$ is the limit function then you always have $L(f,P) = 0, U(f,P) =1$ so $f$ is not Riemann integrable. You can write the limit function as the simple (that term has meaning in Lebesgue integration) function $f=1_\mathbb{Q}$ and **by definition** one has $\int f = \int 1_\mathbb{Q} = m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure (volume as such). For more details you really will have to actually study Riemann integration, measure theory & Lebesgue integration.

Comment: The integral sign represents Lebesgue integral in all my comments. However by definition (as per the approach in Apostol's book) the Lebesgue integral of a step function is defined to be equal to its Riemann integral. It should be obvious to you that Riemann integral of $f_n$ is $0$.

Comment: Just note that $f_n$ is $0$ except at a finite number of points and a finite number of points don't matter in Riemann integration. So the integral of $f_n$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each $f_n$ is integrable because you can check that each lower sum is equal to $0$ and that the upper sums can take (positive) values as small as you want. Therefore, the (Riemann) integral of $f$ is $0$. However, if $f$ is the limit, then every lower sum is $0$ and every upper sum is $1$. Therefore, $f$ is *not* Riemann-integrable.
2. In the case of Lebesgue integration, $f$ is integrable, and its integral is $0$.

Comment: Can you tell me the details of your answer for 2, why you said this ? are you using DCT ?

Comment: Not at all. I am just using that fact that if I have two functions $f,g\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that $\{x\in[a,b]\mid f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ and that $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable, then $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable too and the integrals are equal. Apply this to my function $f$ and take $g$ equal to the null function.

Comment: What about the limit of our function in case of Lebesgue integration? is it integrable?

Comment: I wrote in my answer that it is integrable.

Comment: Yeah I got it I am sorry

Comment: for 1, I do not understand this statement in your answer "that the upper sums can take (positive) values as small as you want." .... or maybe I understand it but just want to be sure that my understanding is correct by asking you for details of this statement.

Comment: For each $\varepsilon>0$, there is some partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ such that the upper sum with respect to $P$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Are you using for 2 that the set of rationals and irrational are dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No. I am using the fact that the set $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.